# Differ special character from int value in UTF-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, special-characters

I would like to store data in a UTF-8 format. Data might be represented by any primitive type and String (standard `DataOutput` API). Each data record is separated by the "record separator" sign (ASCII int - 30, hex - 1E). How to solve the problem of reading this special character? Case example:

1. I am writing strings I can read this character properly no problem there.
2. I am writing integers. How should differ the value 30 between (int)30 and (special char)30?

Comment: Have you checked the UTF-8 encoding table? http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: Even if I store it as:
`ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(N);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
buffer.put(Integer.toHexString(30).getBytes()); // end of record
byte[] bytes = buffer.array();
dataOutput.write(bytes);
Still can be read as int by
dataInput.readInt(); // 828702720`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read `int`s you are reading units of 4 bytes. You will know the difference between the record separator character and an integer because the record separator is not in a unit of 4 bytes.

Comment: Ok, but how can I know when to read 4bytes and when to read less in a stream? In order to catch the record separator. How can I tell the difference. I am trying to write a code which will catch end record signs in a stream and store the bytes in an array as element (each element is separated by the end record sign in the stream).

Comment: That should be in the specification of the stream format you are trying to read. For example, each record must have a fixed length or structure (for example: string and 5 ints), or the length of the record is encoded in the record somehow. Otherwise no-one can parse the stream correctly.

Comment: I think this comment answers my question. I am marking your answer as correct one.